# Copy autoincremented datatable

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have at my test database datatable Tags.

```
ID int autoincrement
Name nvarchar(255)
```

I want to transfer this table to my production database.

How to do it if I want to have the same ids foreach element

The problem is that my start index at testdatable is 15, and some ids don't exist because I removed theirs.

So:

Situation at Test datable

```
15 sport
18 money
30 homework
```

Desired situation at production datatable

```
15 sport
18 money
30 homework
```

At start production datatable is empty, and has autoincrement too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the identity_insert feature on the destination table before inserting the data into the new table.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourNewTable ON

INSERT YourNewTable (ID, Name) SELECT ID,Name FROM YourOldTable

SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourNewTable OFF
```

Comment: Of course you may need a linked server to the dev baox do do this porperly or copy the whole dev table to a staging table onthe prod server and then do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the constraints off for the auto-incrementing field, load your data into the table, and then turn the auto-incrementing field back on.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MY_TABLE ON
INSERT MY_TABLE (Id, Field1) VALUES (15, 'sport')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MY_TABLE OFF
```

or make a backup/restore if the prod database is empty as you said (assuming it's the same database)

Comment: Better to use the select clause than the values clause for this.